# Flutter Search Delegate Architecture (code structure best practices)

Tags: search, flutter

I am relative new to flutter. I was wondering the proper approach in order to implement an AppBar search by using the **Search Delegate** in Flutter. I read various articles on how to do that. However, with dummy data (used in examples) and just no real world scenarios (code structure) there is no hustle.

My use case consists of

- AppBar (home widget - where the search button exists)

  - One tab (other widget - having a service call to DB at init)
  - Another tab (other widget -having a service call to DB at init)

My issue is that I want the search to take place at the results lets say of the first tab. So somehow, I have to pass the values return from the service up to my Home widget and then to search Delegate .

I do not know which is the proper way to do that.

1. InheritedModel/ InheritedWidget ?
2. passing via the constructors from one widget to another (then I will have tight widget connections and I do not want that)
3. Some other way using services ?
4. if any other solution ?

I want the solution to be scalable (as much as possible), in order to make adjustments at near future or add new functionality.

Thanks in advance for your time.

**Update**

I tried the InheritedModel/ InheritedWidget. For some reason, when I tried to access the data from the build method in Delegate I was receiving null object for inherited object. Probably, I was doing something wrong...I will keep trying...

Adding an image in order to clarify the problem with my app structure...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you already know this tutorial?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wm3OiFBZ2xI

I think, it is exactly what you need. My App uses Data from the Cloud Firestore and the search function is implemented like the search function in this tutorial. It works very well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes I have already seen this. I am a fun of the boring flutter show. However, I probably missed something. I ll check it again. My main issue is how from my service (located at one tab), pass the list in order to be searched in a widget located at different place at widget tree, in this case upwards.

Comment: You are welcome.
In my case, I use BLoC and I have my read the Data when the App is starting. After the start, I can pass down the data to the other widgets if I need it.
It is also possible to use Inherited Widgets to access your data from everywhere in your App (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zbm3hjPjQMk  or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ml5uefGgkaA)

Comment: I ll give it a go with the InheritedModel/ InheritedWidget and I will let you know... My worry is that the data is initialize at later stage (inside a tab) and then I have to lift it up to AppBar when the search will be performed and it might need a new setState(). I ll give it a go....

Comment: Why don't you initialize your data when your app is starting? Maybe it is the reason why your get a null object when you try InheritedModel.

Comment: I wanted to "isolate" different section of widget tree as possible and since this part is referring only to widget tree part from tab 1 and below, I placed the service accordingly. Also, went I start building-experimenting on it, Flutter was on beta and there was not an InheritedModel. With InheritedWidget  I thought that it was "expensive" to build all the below widget... I wll have another look at it...

Comment: You can also use BLoC and only call it when you need it, but you will certainly have to use Streams. You read the data asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, I read some tutorials about BLoC pattern... It is pretty powerful. I have to invest on it, as I have not use it before and  it seems a little bit tricky. It is until I get the notion. Thank you for the recommendation.